# Retrieve Image from Node JS Get server response

Tags: node.js, get

I am using a third party API which I send a GET request in Node JS and it responds with XML and an image encoded in base64.

I have tried looking for a third party module to split this out, but these all seem to work on a POST response.
Can Multer use the response from a GET to save the image?

Response is as follows:

```
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file.xml"; filename="file.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 1665


<XML>
.....
</XML>

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="licensePlatePicture.jpg"; 
filename="licensePlatePicture.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 7231

<BASE64 ENCODED IMAGE HERE>
```

I'm looking for an example of how to save the image without having to parse it manually.
Thanks.

Comment: Either use an API, either make your own.

Comment: Can you suggest an API? Everything I have found is aimed at the response from a POST, not a GET.